# Use of undeclared type - Swift - AWS Amplify

Tags: swift, xcode, aws-amplify

I am working through the excellent example app posted here:

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-appsync-events-starter-ios/tree/master/EventsApp

I'm getting the error: "Use of undeclared type..." when recreating EventDetails.swift at line 28:

`var event: Event?`

I am recreating the example app using a different schema and data type. I do not know where the Event data type is defined and therefore I don't know where/how to create the equivalent data type. I my case, I am working with "Store" rather than "Event." When I substitute "Store" for "Event," I get the error mentioned above. Thanks for any help.

Here is the schema.graphql file:

```
type Store @model {
id: ID!
name: String!
number: String!
street_address: Stringx
city: String
state: String
zip_code: String
}
```

Comment: Probably you made a mistake when you create data type. I think you should show more detail from your own code.

Comment: @AhmetSinaUstem I've added the schema.graphql file. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

there is not such type as

> Stringx

that you are using for street_address.